# Where do i find an image's file path in MediaStore

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that picks a  image from the gallery and returns the result. I need to get the file path from that selection and store it for later use. I have looked at similar questions and apparently the file path of the image is stored in the column

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
```

How would anyone know that this is the file path? I've looked at the android documentation on MediaStore and it does not tell you where the file path column is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

use this to get an image from gallery, it will return URI of the image which could be store store for later use

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
            Uri path = data.getData();
        }
    }

}
```